# Bootstrap Tooltip in Vue.js from JSON File

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, bootstrap-4

Currently trying to display Bootstrap tooltips through a json file in Vue.js. My JSON files hold all of the content that should be displayed on a particular component but it isn't initializing Bootstrap. If I simply just copy and paste the Bootstrap 4 tooltip demo to a component like

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" 
data-html="true" title="<em>Tooltip</em> <u>with</u> <b>HTML</b>">
    Tooltip with HTML
</button>
```

What I have above displays perfectly fine with the Bootstrap tooltip being initialized but if I have it displayed in my JSON file such as

```
{
    "text":"Modern vehicles are made up of many different parts. Learning how these parts work together may seem challenging. However, maintaining and operating your car economically and safely is not as difficult as you think.<br><a href=\"{0}California.htm#CONSTRUCTION\" target=\"_blank\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"bottom\" title=\"Tooltip on bottom\">Read more</a> about vehicle’s basic parts and components and how they work together.",
    "text_type":"paragraph"
}
```

The button displays fine but the tooltip is being displayed - at least not the Bootstrap version of it. Any clues?

Relevant code:

```
<template>
<div>                
    <p v-if="hasSubTitle" v-html="slideData.subtitle" class='subtitle'></p>

    <p v-html="slideData.text" class='text-paragraph'></p>

    <div v-if="hasImage" >
        <img v-if="hasImage" :src="playerConfig.GraphicPath + slideData.graphic" class="img-fluid" /> 
    </div>

    <div class='media-div' v-if="hasVideo">
        <videoPlayer 
            ref="videoPlayer"             
            :url="playerConfig.StreamingHTTPSLecture + slideData.graphic"
            :posterUrl ="playerConfig.PosterPath"

             v-on:videoEnded="onVideoEnded" 
             v-on:videoTimeUpdate="onVideoTimeUpdate"
        ></videoPlayer>             
    </div>

</div>  
</template>
```

The relevant property "text" inside of the JSON posted above is being rendered through

```
<p v-html="slideData.text" class="text-paragraph'></p>
```

Comment: Are you using [Bootstrap Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) or are you just trying to use both Bootstrap and Vue? Dynamic behaviors in Bootstrap are not going to play well with Vue unless you handle them in the Vue lifecycle hooks.

Comment: @RoyJ using Bootstrap AND Vue. I was using Bootstrap Vue in the beginning but it's a pretty large code base to only use tooltips. How would I go about them using lifecycle hooks? I initialized all tooltips in Mounted() after we pull dynamic data using $nexTick but still same issue.

Comment: Can you post any relevant code like your Vue Component etc?

Comment: @WildBeard updated description above!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49695544/392102